# Out of range exception in Unity

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine

I create a game in Unity. And I got this error:

```
System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException (System.ExceptionArgument argument, System.ExceptionResource resource)
```

Here is my short code:

```
public class OnlineGame : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<GameObject> domino = new List<GameObject>(7);

    public void Start()
    {
        StartGame();
    }

    private void StartGame()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        { 
            domino[i] = Instantiate(dominoPrefab, new Vector3(11, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        }
    }
}
```

If you need more details, write a comment. Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private List<GameObject> domino = new List<GameObject>(7)
```

`new List<T>(int capacity)` constructor doesn't mean the resulting list will have hold `capacity` objects at beginning. The `Count` of elements in the list will still be 0.

When you use `List` class in c#, it will have `capacity` memory reserved for the list. When you add some elements to the list and its `Count` reaches `capacity`(or close to it, I'm not exactly sure), the list will automatically increase `capacity` by allocating additional memory so that you can add additional element to the list.

Usually when you use `new List<T>()` the list will have initial capacity of 0 where program doesn't know how many `Count` the list can possibly have and will dynamically adjust `capacity` to match your need.

Using `new List<T>(int capacity)` is like telling the program that the list will have at most `capacity` number of elements and list should have that `capacity` ready to avoid overhead of allocating more memory. Of course, when list's `Count` reach `capacity` it will increase as well.

To fix your problem, use `Add` method  instead of assigning to array slot.

```cs
public class OnlineGame : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<GameObject> domino = new List<GameObject>(7);

    public void Start()
    {
        StartGame();
    }

    private void StartGame()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        { 
            // domino[i] = Instantiate(dominoPrefab, new Vector3(11, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            domino.Add(Instantiate(dominoPrefab, new Vector3(11, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @РостиславРоманец question though: If your list shall have a fixed length anyway .. then why not rather simply use an array `GameObject[]` ..?

Comment: It will not has a fixed length. This is the initial length, which will then change.